# How can i make a "delay"?

Tags: vb.net, textbox, delay

I have a Textbox and its showing a progress with text!
How can I make a delay, that the code isnt beeing shown instantly?

```
            MetroTextBox4.Text = MetroTextBox4.Text + "test1" & Environment.NewLine
            MetroTextBox4.Text = MetroTextBox4.Text + "test2" & Environment.NewLine
            MetroTextBox4.Text = MetroTextBox4.Text + "test3" & Environment.NewLine
            MetroTextBox4.Text = MetroTextBox4.Text + "test4" & Environment.NewLine
            MetroTextBox4.Text = MetroTextBox4.Text + "test5" & Environment.NewLine
            MetroTextBox4.Text = MetroTextBox4.Text + "test6" & Environment.NewLine
            MetroTextBox4.Text = MetroTextBox4.Text + "test7" & Environment.NewLine
            MetroTextBox4.Text = MetroTextBox4.Text + "test8" & Environment.NewLine
            MetroTextBox4.Text = MetroTextBox4.Text + "test9" & Environment.NewLine
            MetroTextBox4.Text = MetroTextBox4.Text + "test10" & Environment.NewLine
            MetroTextBox4.Text = MetroTextBox4.Text + "******************************************************" & Environment.NewLine
            MetroTextBox4.Text = MetroTextBox4.Text + "You may experience lag for a bit!" & Environment.NewLine
```

Comment: I want that the Person who is using my tool sees, what is happening right now, as i said it shows a progress of a process.

Comment: If you have long running events, you should have them running on a separate thread. This will allow your UI thread to be free and refresh the screen as you want. You should look and "how to show progress from another thread".

Comment: well, i tried that one time, but i failed really bad, then i didnt want to try it again, but i knew my problem, it was that the 2nd thread wasnt able to control the elements because they were created by another thread.

Comment: Once you figure it out, it is very easy. Do the search I mentioned above and you will find tons of examples. You will be a better programmer for it. If you want the easy (BAD) way out, do what most VB programmer have done for years, `DoEvents`.

Answer (score 1):

Add a timer to your form, available in the toolbox panel of controls that can be added to WinForms.  `Call timer1.Start()` on it when the messages should begin appearing, and register a tick event callback.  When the timer ticks, add the next line of text to the textbox.  Once the last line is added, call `timer1.Stop()` to shut it down.

Comment: hm i had the same idea, but i dont want the same timeing for every message. do i need to do a new timer for each interval then?

Comment: I think you can write to a property on the existing timer to set the interval.  I don't remember if the timer has a single-shot mode that can be used multiple times with different durations, that would be a better fit.

Comment: I dont think you can do this.

Comment: OK, I guess just `.Stop()` the timer after every tick, change `timer1.Interval` to some different number of milliseconds, and `.Start()` again.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a delay between adding each line to the textbox and you aren't worried about not being able to run any other processes inbetween each addition, add this sub to your definitions..

```
Private Sub Delay(msdelay As Integer)
    Dim stpwatch As New Stopwatch
    stpwatch.Start()
    Do
    Loop Until stpwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds >= msdelay
End Sub
```

and in-between each line, add

```
delay(1000)
```

where 1000 is the number of milliseconds delay you want.

However, if you want to be running tests in the background and reporting as the tests progress, you'll most likely need to use a background worker at the very least. Perhaps you could show  the basics of your testing code and depending on how that runs, will make it easier to provide an answer.